# Docker registry "error authorization context"

Tags: docker, authentication, registry, private, swarm

I'm running a private docker registry. It works with `docker login` followed by `docker push` or `docker pull` on both the manager as well as the workers.

However if a new worker joins the swarm it can't pull the images if a service is placed onto it.

So far I have tried the following things:

- `--with-registry-auth` when creating the services on the manager node.
- ran `docker login` successfully at startup of worker nodes before joining the swarm
- creating a `Auth-Header` on the worker following [this](https://github.com/docker/classicswarm/blob/master/docs/swarm-api.md#authenticate-using-username-and-password) instruction from classicswarm

None of which seem to work. The worker nodes still cant pull the images.

The registry always logs

`error authorizing context: basic authentication challange for realm "Registry Realm": invalid authorization credentials`

and returns a 401.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this or what the issue might be ?

When starting a stack on the manager node it can pull the images from the registry after setting the `auth-header` like in the 3rd point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by updating the swarm service with `docker service update --with-registry-auth`.

For some reason `--with-registry-auth` does not work with `docker service create`.

Answer (score -1):

```
docker logout hub-host
docker login hub-host
```